# Replaying events on a service bus without event store

Tags: .net, cqrs, servicebus, event-sourcing

I am trying to design a new service and trying to follow CQRS. I am using ORM (NHibernate) for read and write models. In addition to that, write models are not event sourced. My goal was to keep technologies familiar at first and later on move to NoSQL at the read side and event sourcing at the write side.

I was hoping that using a service bus, I would be able generate new read models just by replaying old events; however I am now stuck. I have a few questions:

1. Does what i am trying to accomplish make any sense? If so, can I do this using *"Service Bus for Windows Server"?* I could not find a way to just create a new subscription and let the **cursor** start from the beginning for a topic. Are events purged when all existing subscribers consume them?
2. If it makes sense but *"Service Bus for Windows Server"* is not up to the job, do you recommend looking for an alternative service bus or implementing event sourcing on the write side?

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need a service bus or event sourcing to replay events. You can simply serialize your events to disk (or any other means of storage) and reload them as needed.

Have a look at the simple example implementation of [**Beingtheworst**](http://beingtheworst.com). The samples can be found at [GitHub](https://github.com/beingtheworst/btw-samples). Especially **E002** and **E003** use serialized events without a service bus or the explicit notion of event sourcing.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion and the useful link. I was thinking of storing these events. However this idea produced many more questions than it answered. Even with event sourcing, I feel like this should be accomplished using a service bus (which has many built-in extra functionality). After catching up, new event handler will be just another read model generator. This was my expectation anyway. Should I clarify my question above?

Comment: @orca If you don't know it already have a look at http://www.nservicebus.com for a full blown service bus solution for .net. The lead developer is Udi Dahan who is one of the major proponents of CQRS as well.

Comment: I read that querying events by time is possible with NServiceBus. I guess this way, I could do most of the work offline. When almost done, subscribe to new events and queue them internally until processing old events is complete. Not exactly I imagined, but would do the job. If you don't mind, I would like to wait for an answer before I try to reinvent the wheel. Well, perhaps it is still too early for CQRS to call anything wheel.